# Bitmap and memory issues, how-to?

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I am porting a boardgame to Android.
The board itself is a 1000x1000 bitmap, which takes about 250k in png format.
It can be zoomed and dragged, for users on small-screen devices, with such a bit of code:

```
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBoardBitmap, left, top, width, width, matrix, true);
board.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), scaledBitmap));
```

You notice that so far I have a member mBoardBitmap, which I use to load my 1000x1000 bitmap onCreate(). It seemed more right to load it once, than repeatedly, when the user moves or zooms. I am beginning to question that strategy, as I will need to add layers to my board, and therefore, a bitmap per layer.

So should I load several 1000x1000 bitmaps (1 megabyte of memory unless I am mistaken) and keep them there, or should I load them anew everytime the user touches the board, which can be quite often?

Secondly, at each MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, the board is redrawn, with the previous two lines of code - what happens of these scaledBitmap and new BitmapDrawable I create? I have never had memory crashes, yet how do I make sure they are recycled/garbage collected?

Best regards.

Comment: Actually it would be 3 or 4 MB for a 1000x1000 bitmap, as you have either 3 or 4 bytes per pixel (Unless you load them using ALPHA_8, in which case it is one byte).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the new memorycache for Android: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html then you only have to redownload/reload images that has been taken out of memory, also you wont crash.